# Problemas con el emulador de android

Tags: android, android-studio

Estaba trabajando bien con el emulador de android y cuando volví a emular mi app ya no visualiza este en la ventana **(Select Deployment Target)**, pues aparece en blanco y el emulador ya esta listo para usarse. Me aparece este error:

> C:\Users\reddr\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay
>    none -netspeed full -avd 4_7WXGA_API_23-nuevo   emulator: WARNING:
>   userdata partition is resized from 694 M to 800 M ERROR: resizing
>   partition e2fsck failed with exit code 8 Creating filesystem with
>   parameters: Size: 69206016 Block size: 4096 Blocks per group: 32768
>   Inodes per group: 4224 Inode size: 256 Journal blocks: 1024 Label: 
>   Blocks: 16896 Block groups: 1 Reserved block group size: 7 Created
>   filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks  Hax is enabled 
>   Hax ram_size 0x40000000  HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt
>   mode.  qemu-system-i386.exe: -drive 
>   if=none,index=2,id=userdata,file=C:\Users\reddr.android\avd\4_7WXGA_API_23-
>   nuevo.avd/userdata-qemu.img: could not open disk image 
>   C:\Users\reddr.android\avd\4_7WXGA_API_23-nuevo.avd/userdata-qemu.img:
>
> Could not open 'C:\Users\reddr.android\avd\4_7WXGA_API_23-
>   nuevo.avd/userdata-qemu.img': Invalid argument

Ya reinicie el equipo **actualice** unos paquetes del **sdk-tools** y hasta borre el emulador y cree uno nuevo y sigo sin poder emular mi app. Espero puedan ayudar, porque no se que paso, de ante  mano gracias.

Comment: Listo, despues de varios intentos y con la orientacion de Jorgesys lo solucione. Reinstale el Android sdk plataform tools y listo ya me detecta el emulador, desconozco que paso. Pero ya funciona :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por el error que muestras:

> if=none,index=2,id=userdata,file=C:\Users\reddr.android\avd\4_7WXGA_API_23-
>   **nuevo.avd/userdata-qemu.img: could not open disk image
>   C:\Users\reddr.android\avd\4_7WXGA_API_23-nuevo.avd/userdata-qemu.img**:

Probablemente fallo la carga de un emulador y dejo un proceso con falla, te sugiero entres al `Task Manager` (Administrador de tareas) de windows y termines el proceso :

> **quemu-system-i386.exe**

trata de nuevamente !.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: gracias Jorgesys lo hare.